# Why this specific answer was treated as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

I've recently flagged one post as a "low quality" post, well, because the "link only" answer option was not available in flag reasons. I'm talking about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20167964/1) in which was a link to an external site, where was the answer to the asked question and so I don't understand why it was taken as a spam.

Could someone explain me, why that post was taken as a spam ?

<sup>P.S. I know the answer should be deleted but why just as a spam ?</sup>

Comment: The link just goes to a deleted post page. Did you review it? If so, can you link us to that review?

Comment: @hichris123, it was already deleted. But sorry, I don't want to quote an answer which was marked as spam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was treated as spam because it is almost certainly spam. And as you said, it should have been deleted regardless due to being a link-only answer. Let's look at the evidence that this was spam:

1. It's a link-only answer.
2. This is the only answer from that user.
3. It was posted on an old question which already had a highly-upvoted accepted answer. There is no explanation of what was unsatisfactory about the existing answer.
4. It links to a blog post.
5. The blog post was posted a day before the answer, which makes it very likely that they have the same author rather than that someone happened to find the blog post in a Google search.

With all the evidence taken together, the chance that this was a post intended to drive traffic to someone's blog is very high.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed it was posted 2 days ago there. And yes, all what you listed makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Good eye on point #5. That's definitely the sort of thing that separates a run-of-the-mill link-only answer from spam.

Comment: Actually, this was the second such post from this user. The first was even spammier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server/20168240#20168240